# How do you change the background color of the < td > tag from vb.net to an html file?

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I'm reading an file .html from vb.net using streamreader to replace some variable declared in .html file as @var1, @var2 etc.

They work fine, but I also need to change the background color to the  tag, that is, I need to send in vb.net the hexadecimal number of the color to

```html
<td id="tdraiting" class="style1" align="left" style="font-size: 13pt; font-family: Verdana; background-color=@mycolor;">
                @var1
            </td>
```

How can I send change @mycolor from VB.net?

This is my code to read the file.

```html
 Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
  Dim bodyms As String
  
  bodyms = reader.ReadToEnd()
  bodyms = bodyms.Replace("@var1", "test")
  
 End Using
```